# Converting hours into minutes in SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

i'm trying to write a regular expression that will convert the hours into minutes.
Currently I have a value which give me the number of hours before the dot and the number of minutes after the dot, for example 6.10 is 6 hours and 10 minute.

Can i use a regular expression to look for the value before the dot and multiply by 60 (to get minutes) and then add the value after the dot (which is already in minutes)?

So as per the example used before, it would do:
(6 * 60) + 10

Thank you!

Comment: I haven't used Teradata regular expressions but..... no. regular expressions find things in strings. They don't do calcs. You need to extract the values and do it seperately.

Comment: Would you know how i can do that? I tried using DATEPART (hh,field) but it gives back an error message saying that hh is now a defined type name. Thank you

Comment: What is the datatype of the field you are searching?

Comment: What is the input you have? Is it a `date` object or always `hh.mm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions is probably an overkill for such a simple string manipulation. All you need is INDEX function to get the location of the dot and SUBSTR function to get hours and minutes.

Dot position:

```
 select INDEX([yourstring], '.')
```

Hours (before the dot):

```
 select SUBSTR([yourstring], 1, INDEX([yourstring], '.')  - 1)
```

Minutes (after the dot):

```
 select SUBSTR([yourstring], INDEX([yourstring], '.') + 1)
```

Comment: You're welcome! Please accept answer if this is what you were after.

Comment: Definitely, how do i do that? Sorry I'm very new in this forum!

Comment: Just click on the check mark next to the answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

If your value "6.10" is stored as a string, convert it to a number first:

```
SET @Input = CAST(@InputString AS FLOAT)
```

Then, use [Modulus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx) and [Floor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178531.aspx).

Total Minutes = The fractional part * 100 + the whole number part * 60.

So if your value `6.10` is contained in a variable named @Input, then you can get the value you wish with

```
SET @Output = (@Input % 1) * 100 + FLOOR(@Input, 0)  * 60
```

If it's in a table then something more like this would be appropriate:

```
SELECT (Input % 1) * 100 + FLOOR(Input, 0) * 60 Output 
FROM   Table
```

The above only works if minutes are zero padded, e.g. 6 hours five minutes = 6.05.  If you instead represent minutes without padding (6 hours five minutes = 6.5) then use the method that [under](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7123641/under) suggests.

Comment: Don't `ROUND`, better `TRUNC` or `CAST(   AS INT)`. Try your approach on `6.55` :)

Answer (score 2):

There's a `STRTOK` function to tokenize a string and then it's just:

```
select '12.34' as x, 
    cast(strtok(x,'.',1) as int) * 60 + cast(strtok(x,'.',2) as int)
```